# Ассемблер направление mov

Tags: ассемблер, gcc

Всю жизнь было mov dest source, сейчас читаю [Ассемблер в Linux для программистов C](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B2_Linux_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_C#.D0.9A.D0.BE.D0.BC.D0.B0.D0.BD.D0.B4.D1.8B) там mov source dest, почему?

Answer (score 4):

есть разные синтаксисы:

`Intel`: `mov dst src`

`AT&T`: `mov src dst`

GNU ассемблер использует `AT&T`